# Why is Git ignoring commits when merging?

Tags: git

We have made changes to one file in two branches. Here is the file commit history on branch A:
[image]

And here is the commit history of that same file on branch B:
[image]

Now when we merge branch A into branch B, we end up with the exact same commit history as branch A. Commit `56dfe991` has gone missing:
[image]

Obviously, this is very disturbing. Especially since we don't know what is causing this. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It seems the commit cb9fca35 already existed in A.

Comment: `git branch -a --contains cb9fca35` will show you all the branches that already contain this commit.

Comment: What commands are you running to perform the merge, or what GUI are you using to manage the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after close investigation, the file (called `CombinedSearchController.js`) had been in a merge conflict and another developer had resolved the conflict with the "using mine/theirs" option. That way the conflicting commit gets left out of the commit history all together.

I found this out by searching for a commit message that had that filename in a list of conflicts, using the command `git log --all --grep='CombinedSearchController.js'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "file commit history" in Git. There's history, and files.

The history is considered at the Git repository granularity, i.e. each commit has a set of parents. This is what you see when you run `git log`, or for a more visual output `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`.

Now, you can ask Git to filter this history on a per-file basis, with e.g. `git log -- file`. This hides commits that do not touch the file, *but also does some history simplifications* to hide commits that do not contribute to the file history. This is documented in details in the ["History Simplification" section of git log's documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification).

Essentially, when reaching a merge commit, if one of the parent of the merge commit does not introduce change to the file, then this parent is ignored.

As a result, for example, `git log` and `git log .` at the root of a project may show different histories.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found that issue. Merging always adds all commit hashes into history, unless you have overriden them after with a rebase (which changes the hash id, even tho the changes for the file remain).

Go to your branch B after the merge and run:

```
git branch --contains commitHashYouAreLookingFor
```

It should show you all branches that contain that commit, one of those should be B. If you then want to find what was the merge that included that commit in B do:

```
git log --merges commitHashYouAreLookingFor
```

hope this helps.